# Coin game strategy

Tags: game-theory

**PROBLEM**

Suppose two players play a coin game. They both have a coin and can choose themselves what the probability is that they will play head $H$. So for player $i$, the chance he gets head is $p_i$, $i = {1,2}$.
If both coins turn out to be the same, player $1$ will win, if they differ, player $2$ will win.

Show that $(p_1,p_2)$ = $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is the unique Nash Equilibrium of this game.

Comment: In order to help you do your homework (notably different from us doing your homework) it is paramount that you include in your question: 1. Your attempts on the problem; 2. What part of it you're stuck on (see also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803)). If you [edit] your question to provide this information, it is much more likely that we can help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: What is the game?  Once they have chosen heads or tails, what happens?

Comment: rewards are missing in this questions are they not? Are both players awarded when their coins show same side up?

Comment: @Lord_Farin Sorry, I forgot to add that I didn't know how to approach this problem, I am working on this problem with a friend right now and we are stuck..

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, if both coins are heads or tails, then player 1 will win the two coins, if they differ, player 2 will win.

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal Could edit your post and include that information please?

Comment: @BISHD Done, mein Freund

Answer (score 1):

This is just the question for the normal form game

\begin{matrix}
& & Player 2 &  \\
& & H & T \\
Player 1&H& (1,-1) & (-1,1) \\
 &T& (-1,1) & (1,-1) 
\end{matrix}
(You could take another payoff-distribution as well)

called **"matching pennies"** and you're asked to find the mixed-strategy equilibrium, which is unique in this case and it is exactly $$(p_1,p_2)= (0.5,0.5)$$
as you can read [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pennies). There is no Nash equilibrium in pure strategies. If you have trouble understanding how to find the equilibrium, leave a comment with a question ;-)

Comment: Thank you but how did you get the tablem and how can you say this for general $p$?

Comment: This table is just an example as you haven't specified, what "wining" means in terms of payoffs. For me, wining means a payoff of $1$ in contrast to loosing which gives $-1$. It would be a different setting if the coin is **not** fair. But the players only choose the probability of her actions, not of the coin. What do you mean with general $p$? $p_i \in [0,1]$ are just probabilites.

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I didn't give a downvote

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal You can improve your question by including payoffs (for example the payoffs I used) for the players in case of winning and loosing.